# Parse error with a simple CSV import into Clickhouse

Tags: csv, clickhouse

I have an extremely simple CSV I'm trying to import into clickhouse with no success. The create table statement is:

```sql
CREATE TABLE staging.EloLBK
(
    `Month` DateTime64(3),
    `1958` Int32,
    `1959` Int32,
    `1960` Int32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PRIMARY KEY Month
ORDER BY Month
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

The CSV data looks like this:

```
"Month", "1958", "1959", "1960"
"JAN",  340,  360,  417
"FEB",  318,  342,  391
"MAR",  362,  406,  419
"APR",  348,  396,  461
"MAY",  363,  420,  472
"JUN",  435,  472,  535
"JUL",  491,  548,  622
"AUG",  505,  559,  606
"SEP",  404,  463,  508
"OCT",  359,  407,  461
"NOV",  310,  362,  390
"DEC",  337,  405,  432
```

My import statement is:

```sql
INSERT INTO EloLBK SELECT * FROM file('EloLBK/*.csv', 'CSVWithNames', '"Month" datetime64, "1958" integer, "1959" integer, "1960" integer')
```

The error coming back from clickhouse is:

```
Code: 27. DB::Exception: Cannot parse input: expected '"' before: '417\n"FEB",  318,  342,  391\n"MAR",  362,  406,  419\n"APR",  348,  396,  461\n"MAY",  363,  420,  472\n"JUN",  435,  472,  535\n"JUL",  491,  548,  622\n"AUG",  505,':
Row 1:
Column 0,   name: Month, type: DateTime64(3), parsed text: "<DOUBLE QUOTE>JAN<DOUBLE QUOTE>,  340,  360,  "ERROR
Code: 27. DB::ParsingException: Cannot parse input: expected '"' before: '417\n"FEB",  318,  342,  391\n"MAR",  362,  406,  419\n"APR",  348,  396,  461\n"MAY",  363,  420,  472\n"JUN",  435,  472,  535\n"JUL",  491,  548,  622\n"AUG",  505,'. (CANNOT_PARSE_INPUT_ASSERTION_FAILED) (version 21.12.1.8928 (official build))

: While executing CSVRowInputFormat: While executing File. (CANNOT_PARSE_INPUT_ASSERTION_FAILED)
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell ClickHouse to do a best effort guess by passing the option `date_time_input_format='best_effort'`, for example:

```
INSERT INTO EloLBK SELECT * FROM file('EloLBK/*.csv', 'CSVWithNames', '"Month" datetime64, "1958" integer, "1959" integer, "1960" integer') settings date_time_input_format='best_effort';
```

Will lead to:

```
┌───────────────────Month─┬─1958─┬─1959─┬─1960─┐
│ 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 │  340 │  360 │  417 │
│ 2000-02-01 00:00:00.000 │  318 │  342 │  391 │
│ 2000-03-01 00:00:00.000 │  362 │  406 │  419 │
│ 2000-04-01 00:00:00.000 │  348 │  396 │  461 │
│ 2000-05-01 00:00:00.000 │  363 │  420 │  472 │
│ 2000-06-01 00:00:00.000 │  435 │  472 │  535 │
│ 2000-07-01 00:00:00.000 │  491 │  548 │  622 │
│ 2000-08-01 00:00:00.000 │  505 │  559 │  606 │
│ 2000-09-01 00:00:00.000 │  404 │  463 │  508 │
│ 2000-10-01 00:00:00.000 │  359 │  407 │  461 │
│ 2000-11-01 00:00:00.000 │  310 │  362 │  390 │
│ 2000-12-01 00:00:00.000 │  337 │  405 │  432 │
└─────────────────────────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: That's super helpful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some more messing around, it appears the error message is just a bit misleading. The actual issue is that clickhouse is (understandably) unable to parse the month as a datetime.

The following CSV input works fine:

```
"Month","1958","1959","1960"
"1970-01-01T00:00:00","340","360","417"
"1970-01-02T00:00:00","318","342","391"
```